# Python - Decode UTF-16 file with BOM

Tags: python, file, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I have a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) [LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes) file with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). I'd like to flip this file in to UTF-8 without BOM so I can parse it using Python.

The usual code that I use didn't do the trick, it returned unknown characters instead of the actual file contents.

```
f = open('dbo.chrRaces.Table.sql').read()
f = str(f).decode('utf-16le', errors='ignore').encode('utf8')
print f
```

What would be the proper way to decode this file so I can parse through it with `f.readlines()`?

Comment: If this is on Windows, try opening the file in binary mode and see if that helps.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Firstly, you should read in binary mode, otherwise things will get confusing.

Then, check for and remove the BOM, since it is part of the file, but not part of the actual text.

```
import codecs
encoded_text = open('dbo.chrRaces.Table.sql', 'rb').read()    #you should read in binary mode to get the BOM correctly
bom = codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE                                      #print dir(codecs) for other encodings
assert encoded_text.startswith(bom)                           #make sure the encoding is what you expect, otherwise you'll get wrong data
encoded_text = encoded_text[len(bom):]                         #strip away the BOM
decoded_text = encoded_text.decode('utf-16le')                 #decode to unicode
```

Don't encode (to `utf-8` or otherwise) until you're done with all parsing/processing. You should do all that using unicode strings.

Also, `errors='ignore'` on `decode` may be a bad idea. Consider what's worse: having your program tell you something is wrong and stop, or returning wrong data?

Answer (score 18):

This works in Python 3:

```
f  = open('test_utf16.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-16').read()
print(f)
```

Comment: If you set encoding only to **utf-16**, you don't have to eliminate BOM manually.

Comment: edited to make it just be `utf-16`, it doesn't seem to be documented, but the encoding of `utf-16` does seem to automatically handle the BOM. if you use `utf-16le`, it still _works_, but the BOM is still there, which you can remove yourself by using string functions and `codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE`