# Can't read log file but can read after copy paste to notepad

Tags: python

**Task:**

My task is to compare my strings in first column inside of [sha1_vsdt.csv](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8hpn3bxut8ccx47/sha1_vsdt.csv/file) and strings in [trendx.log](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0527h287c0ymhxj/trendx.log/file): When it matched, it should get the description inside of the log file then put it in the third column of csv, otherwise put undetected

But the `trendx.log` can't be read, what I did is - I copied the contents of trendx.log then paste it in a notepad then after I saved it, it is readable.
Here is the the readable log file - [trend2.log](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ruvpc73nh4ac8dj/trend2.log/file). I think the unicode format is the problem.

How can I read this log file guys? is there anyway to convert this? I already tried to encode this using `utf-16le` but I only prints 3 lines

**Here is my code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io
import shutil


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
logtext = "trendx.log"

#Log data into dataframe using genfromtxt
logdata = np.genfromtxt(logtext,invalid_raise = False,dtype=str, comments=None,usecols=np.arange(16))
logframe = pd.DataFrame(logdata)
#print (logframe.head())

#Dataframe trimmed to use only SHA1, PRG and IP
df2=(logframe[[10,11]]).rename(columns={10:'SHA-1', 11: 'DESC'})
#print (df2.head())

#sha1_vsdt data into dataframe using read_csv
df1=pd.read_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",delimiter=",",error_bad_lines=False,engine = 'python',quoting=3)
#Using merge to compare the two CSV

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='SHA-1', how='left').fillna('undetected')
df1['DESC'] = df['DESC'].values

df1.to_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",index=False)
```

Output in csv using: `trendx.log` all is undetected from row 1 - 584

[image]

Correct output in csv using: `trend2.log`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Decode UTF-16 file with BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459020/python-decode-utf-16-file-with-bom)

Comment: The `file` command helps. `file trendx.log` => `Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: can u explain further the code, so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file is encoded as UTF-16-LE. Pass in the `encoding` flag when you read the file, like this:

`logdata = np.genfromtxt(logtext, invalid_raise=False,dtype=str, comments=None,usecols=np.arange(16)`**`, encoding='utf_16-le'`**`)`